# Fetching entity of multiple level using criteria hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following structure:

**A.java**

```
private long id;
private String name;
private B bObj;
// getter-setter
```

**B.java**

```
private long id;
private List<B> bList;
//getter-setter
```

As you can see the structure is recursive.

Now I want to write a Criteria that fetches an object of A along with `bObj`, `bObj.bList`, `bObj.bList.bList`, `bObj.bList.bList.bList` & so on where no. of level of join is not known.

Any other way except Criteria is also welcome.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you set fetch type to LAZZY on List bList; it could be enough, but I don'tknow if it isn necessary to set Maximum outer join fetch depth for hibernate to max level of bLists.

Comment: Do you mean `criteria.setFetchMode("bList", FetchMode.LAZY);` ?

Comment: I mean put to put annotation like this   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)) to your entity definition or in your xml with entity definition.

Comment: That I know & it definitely works. But that would load `bList` with its children & subchildren each time I fetch it. I don't want to do this each time. There is only one such requirement whee I need to fetch all of them.